# Most efficient way to get the same data in parent and child component in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, network-efficiency

I actually make two calls from the same API to get the same data. One from the parent component and one from the child component.

This is the way I get my data in **`parent.js`** and **`child.js`**

```
     ...
     this.cyclistService.cyclistInfo().subscribe(
            (cyclist) => {
               this.cyclist = cyclist
            }
        )
     ...
```

In order to reduce network latency, should I make the API call in both places or just pass the data locally ?

Comment: For future reference, this question was discussed on Meta on [14 May 2021 05:51:02Z](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407643/12892553) and [14 May 2021 11:16:20Z](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407653/12892553); also note that the current question is "*should I make the API call in both places or just pass the data locally ?*" and there are currently 2 comments, one that suggests using "*the first solution*" while the second "*recommend using the second solution*"

Comment: Questions asking "should I" are almost guaranteed to be opinion-based questions. In times like these, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ yourself and do what the data shows is more efficient in your scenario. We can't reliably emulate the same situation as you when it comes to network latencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the answer given from [ryan-m,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208273/ryan-m) which might help someone else who has the same question.

«*Just pass the data locally. Redundant API calls are always going to be slower because network latency on a phone is potentially a lot, and you could have one fail but not the other, and all sorts of fun things to think about. Reducing the number of API calls you need to make from a mobile device is always good if you have a way to do it without sacrificing correctness.* »